# Simple Differential Equation $\displaystyle xy \frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{x^2-y^2-x^2y^2-1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve

$\displaystyle xy \frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{x^2-y^2-x^2y^2-1}$

I started off by assuming $y^2=V$ but could not get far

Comment: What's the reference of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so simple, I think.  Maple doesn't find a closed form solution.  Are you sure
you're asked to solve the DE in "closed form", and that you've quoted it correctly?  It's not, perhaps, 
$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - x^2 y^2 - 1}$?

Comment: +1 I agree. Mathematica also gets nowhere and it looks strange.

Comment: Thank you Robert. It is mentioned as such in the book I am referring to. But now I am beginning to doubt its correctness as Maple couldn't give closed form solution.